# How to pass a variable to another function in Golang and get it back afterward

Tags: go

I'm new to GO, and I want to achieve something basic. passing a couple of variables (**ordersPubsub, ordersWriter**) to a function and get them back afterward.

**main.go**

```
var rdb *redis.Client
var ordersPubsub redis.PubSub
var ordersWriter csv.Writer

func main() {
    rdb = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Network:  "tcp",
        Addr:     "addr",
        Password: "password",
    })
    go utils.SaveData("orders", rdb, &ordersPubsub, &ordersWriter)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    ordersWriter.Flush()
}
```

**utils/subscriber.go**

```
func SaveData(channelSub string, rdb *redis.Client, pubSub *redis.PubSub, writer *csv.Writer) {
    csvfile, err := os.Create("data/" + channelSub + ".csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed creating file: %s", err)
    }
    writer = csv.NewWriter(csvfile)
    ctx := context.TODO()
    pubSub = rdb.Subscribe(ctx, channelSub)
    for msg := range channel {
        order := Order{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg.Payload), &order)
        var row []string
        row = append(row, order.OrderID)
        writer.Write(row)
    }
}
```

I tested another type of the variable and it works as expected, but for this, I'm getting the following errors :

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0xf5788d]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

You are passing pointers to a function, and then setting those pointers in the function. That only assigns the copy of the pointer passed in, not the actual variable you passed to the function in the first place.

For your specific problem, you don't need to pass those variables to the goroutine because the goroutine can already access and set them. In the general case, you have to set the contents of those pointers:

```
   *writer = *csv.NewWriter(csvfile)
   ctx := context.TODO()
   *pubSub = *rdb.Subscribe(ctx, channelSub)
```

Or, you have to declare them as pointers, pass the address of them:

```
var ordersPubsub *redis.PubSub
var ordersWriter *csv.Writer

...
*writer = csv.NewWriter(csvfile)
ctx := context.TODO()
*pubSub = rdb.Subscribe(ctx, channelSub)
```

Also note that you will be using `ordersWriter` from two goroutines without synchronization, so it will be a data race.